# Minimize use of if...else constructs to get the right value for an object property with some design pattern if possible

Tags: javascript, if-statement, design-patterns, refactoring

I want to assign a value to property when creating an object based on lot of conditions. Currently I'm using a separate function to get the value of the property, something like this:

```
function getLocationId(currency, storeCode, isBundle) {
  if (currency === 'MYR') {
    if (storeCode === 'store-1') {
      return 1;
    } else if (storeCode === 'store-2') {
      return 2;
    }
  } else if (currency === 'SGD') {
    if (storeCode === 'store-1') {
      return 3;
    } else if (storeCode === 'store-2') {
      // This function can return the same value for a different condition
      return 2;
    } else if (!storeCode && !isBundle) {
      return 8;
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
  // More conditions, with some involving `isBundle`
}

function getAccountId(currency, storeCode, paymentMethod) {
  // Function definition similar to getLocationId
  // with checks for currency, storeCode, paymentMethod
}

function getRequestObject(event) {
  return {
    .
    .
    .
    location: getLocationId(event.currency, event.storeCode, event.item.isBundle),
    account: getAccountId(event.currency, event.storeCode, event.paymentMethod),
    .
    .
    .
  };
}
```

I feel like there are a lot of if...else constructs used with nested checks again. Is doing that even a good idea? Is there any design pattern I can use to build a request object with the right location ID and account ID based on the parameter `event` in `getRequestObject`?

PS:  I'm not returning the integer value in the actual codebase, instead using this library called `node-config` and storing these IDs in a JSON file which I can later retrieve with `config.get('propertyName')`.

Comment: You can make an array of objects containing all the related data together in each object. Put this array into some other file and you just have to find by the key and return other properties from that object.

Comment: can you show some more conditions with `currency` and `isBundle`? has your data of return value a structure which is same for certain values?

Comment: @NinaScholz Alright, I'll edit the question and add a few more conditions. And yes, the function `getLocationId` or `getAccountId` can return the same value for different checks made with if...else.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner approach without `else` statements after `return` statements.

```
function getLocationId(currency, storeCode, isBundle) {
    if (currency === 'MYR') {
        if (storeCode === 'store-1') return 1;
        if (storeCode === 'store-2') return 2;
        // other if or return a default value for this currency
    }
    if (currency === 'SGD') {
        if (storeCode === 'store-1') return 3;
        if (storeCode === 'store-2') return 2;
        if (!storeCode && !isBundle) return 8;
    }
}
```